# PHP How to edit HTML element Content?

Tags: php, html

Just like `$('#elementid').html('html code');` but in PHP. Is there a way to change live content with PHP without reloading page? Tried

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#element').html('<p>I am a text</p>');      
</script>'
?>
<div id='element'>I will be changed!</div>
```

Is there any shorter way, that one also not works everytime.

Comment: php is server site language can't control content without reloading use js or ajax

Comment: I can't use it, because i need also php variables to be displayed

Comment: By ajax you can print also your php variable values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post('test.php','',function(response){
   $('#element').html(res); 
});
```

**test.php**

```
$name = "sham";
echo "this is my variable $name";
```

**Output of Html**

```
<div id='element'>this is my variable sham</div>
```

Comment: This should not je AJAXed IMO, this is abusing the power :)

Comment: Why are you using post when you are only getting stuff?

Comment: OP wants this @DanielCheng